# Rails - Destroy all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to destroy all records in my database in one line, without specifying my models?

Say I have three models `User` `Picture` `Post`. I can call `User.all.destroy_all` etc, but can I collect all records without specifying the models themselves?

Comment: So you want to delete data from all the tables of database?

Comment: You can use the `db:reset` rake task to do a database drop and setup correspondingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sebastian Palma says you can do the rake task `rake db:reset` which will drop and setup your database.

Alternatively you can get all the descendants of `ActiveRecord`.  If you're in development mode you'll need to eager_load first.

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

Then you could do

```
ActiveRecord.descendants.each(&:destroy_all)
```

**PLEASE BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL!  THE ABOVE WILL DELETE ALL RECORDS IN YOUR DATABASE TABLES!**